# XML data gives error while trying to fetch inside the class

Tags: xml

I am working on winform application with XML.

Please find the attached XML. 
[image]
I have used the following class to fetching the data.

public class Task
    {

```
    public int Screens { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Employees { get; set; }



    public static Task[] FromXml(string sourceXml)
    {

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceXml)))
        {

            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cinema[]));

            return xs.Deserialize(ms) as Cinema[];

        }

    }

}
```

I got the following error while deserializing the data in xml.

**Error:There is an error in XML document (1, 1).**

Please help me..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi mareckmareck, I have closed the </Task> tag and same problem issue occurs still.. Please have a look on the same... Thanks!

Comment: Are those hyphens part of xml? Try to validate your xml file first using some validator, for example wc3 : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp. Also make sure the xml file is properly encoded in UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Error in line 1, column 1: Do you have a space, or a blank line, before the XML Declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)?

If so, remove it. There should be *nothing* before the XML Declaration except (if you have one) the Byte Order Mark.

Comment: Hi, There is no space or blank line. Can u pls have a look on the same. Thanks!

Comment: I'd have to see the actual file. There's nothing obviously wrong with the XML you've shown us... but I don't recognize the language your code is written in, so I have no opinion on whether you're setting up the parser correctly.